# JQuery AJAX Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I save the return of the JQuery AJAX load() function in a variable?
For example
var temp="";

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
```

So instead of saving the return in div1, I want to save it in the variable temp.

Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` that automagically inserts the content as well.
You can use `$.get` instead if you want to store the data in a variable instead of directly inserting to an element

```
$.get('demo_test.txt', function(data) {
    var temp = $('<div />', {html : data}).find('#p1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$( "#div1" ).load( "demo_test.txt", function(data) {
  var temp = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#div1" ).load( "demo_test.txt", function( response, status, xhr ) {
     var saved_response = response;
});
```

Look more at https://api.jquery.com/load/